# Dominated Convergence Theorem Explanation?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Explanations for DCT are out everywhere on the internet - I know. I have a specific question pertaining to how this was explained in a stats lecture I had.

X - random variable
w - realization(s)

```
If a sequence of random variables converge to X(w), Xi(w) converges to X(w) and |Xi(w)|
is less than or equal to Y(x) for all i and E[Y(w)]. Then E[Xi] converges to E[X].
```

```
Conclusion: E[of the sequence] converges to E[of the limit]
```

```
Xi is dominated by Y.
```

The way it was described is pretty messy, imo. Would anyone have a better explanation in this context, in a simple, but more detailed manner? It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by detail, but here's my take...

Consider a sequence $X_n$ of random variables such that for all $n$, $|X_n|\leq Y$ for some random variable $Y\geq0$, with $E(Y)<\infty$.

DCT says that if $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ for each $\omega$, then $E(X_n)\to E(X)$.

NB: What is wrote is pointwise convergence, which can be replaced by a.s. convergence.

Example: Consider the probability space $([0,1),\mathcal B,\lambda)$ (where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on this Borel $\sigma$ algebra) and let $X_n:[0,1)\to [0,1]$ defined by $X_n(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\leq \dfrac{1}{n}$ and $X_n(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

Then you can check that for every $\omega\in[0,1)$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ so that $\omega>\dfrac{1}{n}$ for all $n>N$ so for all these $n$ we have $X_n(\omega)=0$. Hence for this $\omega$, we have $X(\omega)=\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)=0$. This is true for each $\omega\in[0,1)$ so $X\equiv 0$.

Now note that $X_n\leq 1$ for all $n$ and $E(1)=1<\infty$, and $X_n\to 0$.

So by DCT, $E(X_n)$ should converge to $E(X)$.

Indeed, $E(X_n)=1\times\dfrac{1}{n}+0\times(1-\dfrac{1}{n})=\dfrac{1}{n}\to0=E(X)$, so DCT is verified!